# what's the best data structure for pattern matching within a vocabulary?

Tags: data-structures, pattern-matching, trie

Given a set of vocabulary, what's the best data structure that can be used to find all the words within the vocabulary that matches a given sub string?

Suppose "Ap" is the substring,
"Apple" and "Application" should be returned.
Since in this case, "Ap" is at the start of the two strings, I can think of the use of **Tries.**

But what if the substring to be matched can be found anywhere in the words of the vocabulary?
Eg:  If "ap" is given, "shape" should also be returned since "ap" occurs in "shape".

The vocabulary set is very large.

Comment: What defines best? Fastest, smallest. What have you tried. There are ways you can optimise through taking advantage of constraints, e.g case insensitive, but there's no magic wand.

Comment: I did something like this once for a scrabble word finder, but it had a lot more constraints to optimise on and needed to find all words with a pattern like A?P. It essentially broke the vocabulary into a dictionary of dictionary of lists. So I had a dictionary of all the words with an A in them, which held a dictionary of lists for what position in the word A was in. Used a lot of memory and took some time to load up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want is a [suffix tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suffix_tree). This stores *all suffixes* of a (set of) strings in a trie (in your case, the set of words).  Each leaf of the trie is associated with the the set of strings that have that suffix.

When searching for a substring, you simply match the substring at the root of trie; your substring must be a prefix of some suffix or there is no match.  Discovering the *existence* of a match is linear time in the length of the substring.   To determine *all* matching words, you have to enumerate all leaves of the trie accessible from the point where the match completes.  That is a tree walk problem; if the tree has significant branching, it might be bit expensive.

You could precompute, for each trie node, the set of associated words; this is likely to be pretty big, but now you have an extremely fast determination of matching words.

If you only need the members of the set to examine until you find one with some nice property, I'd stick with the enumeration.